# How to copy lines from "before" version of diff, without including garbage?

Tags: git, github

In the github commit list I clicked a commit which I wanted to partially revert by hand (without using `git revert`). In the left-hand pane of the diff I found some code that I wanted to copy into the current version (in my IDE), but when I selected it, the minus-signs signifying "removed" got selected too. So if I then copied the selection, I'd have to remove them manually.

**How do I copy the text easily, without including garbage?**

One way I've found is: open in GitHub the commit *before* the one I care about, then in the top right click "View". This shows the revision I need, and selection works fine (doesn't include garbage). But that's a roundabout way.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use `revert`?

Comment: @Vampire: Lots of reasons. 1. I want, in the current branch, to revert a commit from an ancestor branch. That's a fairly atypical operation, so I prefer to do it manually so I don't have to remember whether `git revert` handles it correctly. 2. I don't want to have to check if the commit in question changes other things that I've forgotten too. I know very well which part of it I want. 3. Some code was added by the commit in question. Now, when I "revert", I don't want this code to disappear from HEAD, I want it to become commented out.

Comment: Use a proper diff tool, not a web interface.

Comment: Commits do not belong to branches. And revert just applies the changes of the given commit in reverse, so yes, it should work fine. If you then add `--no-commit` to the equation, you can easily review the changes done by revert and only commit the ones you want.